# Is it possible to use the blackd formatter for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Is it possible to use the blackd formatter for python in VsCode?  I would like to see the performance increase from using blackd if possible.

**From the Docs**

> blackd is a small HTTP server that exposes Black’s functionality over a simple protocol. The main benefit of using it is to avoid paying the cost of starting up a new Black process every time you want to blacken a file.

Comment: "the performance increase" compared to what? If the documentation says that having a server running is faster than having to start up Black every time then it probably is indeed the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's current not possible, but if you would like to see support added then please leave an upvote reaction on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3336.

Comment: Frankly, I'd rather see this integrated with black so that it's just a matter of running the server (and maybe pointing at it): e.g. `black --server-port=8080 ...` would translate any options into request headers and submit to blackd.